# Unable to find an element with the text: For your shared interests

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I have written the following test:

```
test("Search for particular text", async () => {
    render(<Home/>)
    expect(screen.getByText("TARGADS")).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText("WE BRING YOU TO THE NEXT OF THE ADVERTISEMENT")).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText("For your shared interests")).toBeInTheDocument()
    screen.debug()
})
```

The last test failed because of:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: For your shared interests. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements.
```

when I look into the rendered DOM:

```
...
<div
    class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-sm-12"
  >
    <div
      class="MuiGrid-root makeStyles-textContainer-4 MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-sm-12 MuiGrid-grid-md-6"
      style="background: rgb(255, 10, 84);"
    >
      <h4
        class="MuiTypography-root makeStyles-text-5 MuiTypography-h4"
      >
        For your shared interests, you will receive 5% of our earnings for every single interestSo do not hesitate to share. Share more earn more!!!
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div
      class="MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-align-items-xs-center MuiGrid-justify-xs-center MuiGrid-grid-xs-12 MuiGrid-grid-md-6"
    >
      <img
        alt="Earning money"
        class="makeStyles-mediaIcon-6"
        src="money.svg"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text appears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you use the `"WE BRING YOU TO THE NEXT OF THE ADVERTISEMENT"` text in the same way?

Comment: usually you need to use the react dom returned by `render`, like `const screen = render(<Home/>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that output because the screen couldn't find any DOM element that has innerText "For your shared interests".

This line:

```
expect(screen.getByText("For your shared interests")).toBeInTheDocument()
```

Will try to get anything in the DOM that contains just `'For your shared interests'` inside. So, based on your output HTML that line should be something like this:

```
expect(screen.getByText("For your shared interests, you will receive 5% of our earnings for every single interestSo do not hesitate to share. Share more earn more!!!")).toBeInTheDocument()
```

But that looks really complicated, and assumming that you are showing some dynamic data there, you could use a regular expression in `getByText` function. Like this:

```
expect(screen.getByText(/For your shared interests/)).toBeInTheDocument()
```